# FPGA Internal Timing constraint failing

Tags: fpga, verilog, intel-fpga, timing-analysis, fifo

I'm currently trying to implement an IP-Core on a **Cyclone V 5CSEBA6U23I7** FPGA-HPS System using Altera Quartus II and TimeQuest Analyzer.
The Verilog code pasted below produces a timing problem, namely the assignment **`fifo_wdata_289[255:0] <= {fifo_out,fifo_wdata_289[255:16]};`**, which writes the output of one FIFO into another FIFO register array.
The FIFOs in use are asynchronous, but the signals used are on the same clock domain.
This is being placed on the chip with a clock skew of **-2.255 ns**, which is a little bit less than a whole period (**288 MHz clock => 3.47 ns**), and makes TimeQuest complain, that the constraints are being violated.
The recommendation of TimeQuest is to **Reduce the levels of combinational logic for the path** (Issue **Long Combinational Path**) with Extra levels of combinational logic = 1.
The 288 MHz clock is generated via PLL and I'm using Timeconstraint files (sdc) with commands derive_pll_clocks and derive_clock_uncertainty.
My question now is how to solve this problem, since I only have one layer of combinational logic (Demuxer and routing, as suggested by the assignment) and thus have no idea how to reduce that. Is there any other way I can make sure the timing requirement is met, or is there a better way to program this statemachine?
Thanks for your help.

```
            case(stateProc)
                2'b00:
                begin
                    if(~fifo_empty&~fifo_full_289)
                    begin
                        fifo_wdata_289[255:0] <= {fifo_out,fifo_wdata_289[255:16]};
                        fifo_wdata_289[287:256] <= {2'b11,fifo_wdata_289[287:258]};
                        if(imgSize >= maxImgSize - 32'd2)//image done, transmit data and fire irq
                        begin
                            fifo_wdata_289[288] <= 1;
                            stateProc <= 2'b01;
                            imgSize <= 32'd0;
                        end
                        else if(fifo_wdata_289[258])//process transfer without irq //258 high means that 256 has been written in this cycle and 258 in the previous cycle
                        begin
                            fifo_wdata_289[288] <= 0;
                            stateProc <= 2'b01;
                            imgSize <= imgSize + 32'd2;
                        end
                        else//accumulate more data
                        begin
                            fifo_wdata_289[288] <= 0;
                            stateProc <= 2'b00;
                            imgSize <= imgSize + 32'd2;
                        end
                    end
                    else
                    begin
                        fifo_wdata_289 <= fifo_wdata_289;
                        imgSize <= imgSize;
                        stateProc <= 2'b00;
                    end
                end
                2'b01:
                begin
                    fifo_wdata_289 <= fifo_wdata_289;
                    imgSize <= imgSize;
                    stateProc <= 2'b11;
                end
                2'b11:
                begin
                    fifo_wdata_289 <= 0;
                    imgSize <= imgSize;
                    stateProc <= 2'b00;
                end
            endcase
```

EDIT:

The TimeQuest failing paths look mostly like this:
Slack:
-3.178  

From Node:
soc_system:u0|CamConnector:camconnector_0|FIFO_289:FIFO_inst_289|dcfifo:dcfifo_component|dcfifo_6up1:auto_generated|wrptr_g[0]

To Node:
soc_system:u0|CamConnector:camconnector_0|fifo_wdata_289[267]

EDIT2:
I'm currently using MLAB cells as FIFO storage, which are rated for 290 MHz.
Both FIFOs are asynchronous and have a synchronizaton setting of 3.

Timing closure Recommandations of TimeQuest reports the following two issues:

1. Unbalanced Combinational Logic
2. Long Combinational Path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> since I only have one layer of combinational logic (Demuxer and routing, as suggested by the assignment)

No you don't have that. There is also the clearing in stateProc==2'b11. But I assume the Cyclone LUTs are big enough that it can encompass an extra AND gate at the same time.

But I suggest you also post the failing path as reported by the tool. Because something does not add up here. The path for the  fifo_wdata_289[288] is more complex and you say that it **does** pass timing. I would not be surprised if the mux control signals: fifo_empty, fifo_full_289, stateProc etc. are also in the failing timing path together with the drive tree as you control a lot of FF's from one signal.

If not you can really only run at a lower speed. There is no use in fiddling with the clock as the circuit uses it's own signals (**fifo_wdata_289**[255:0] <= {fifo_out,**fifo_wdata_289[255:16]**};) Thus if you skew or invert the clock, fifo_wdata_289[255:16] will come out later and thus again fail timing. You may be lucky and the fifo_out is arriving late and causing the timing error but again look at the timing report of the failing path.

Anyway, skewing a clock is something which can be done in an ASIC but I would not try it an FPGA. I don't think you have the fine control to skew one clock 
~300ps against another. But I have not us cyclones so maybe....

---

Update:
Just what I expected: The path start at the wrptr_g... I assume that is the write pointer which is probably compared to the read pointer which makes the fifo_full/empty flags which control the mux.

The best way to get rid of the timing issue is to make a registered version of the full/empty flags. That may mean you have to redesign some of the rest of the circuit.

If the FIFO is a synchronous one there is a trick to generate synchronous full/empty flags. You check if the level is ONE and on a read but not write you synchronous set the 'empty' flag. See [here](https://www.verilog.pro/fifo.html) for some free example code of FIFO's which have that feature. Unfortunately that does not work with a-synchronous FIFOs.

Comment: I've taken a look at the post-fitting RTL schema and apparently the LUTs are big enough to implement this as a single logic block operation, but apparently I should have read the warnings more closely. The top failing paths are starting from an internal FIFO register (FIFO_289:FIFO_inst_289|dcfifo:dcfifo_component|dcfifo_6up1:auto_generated|wrptr_g[0]) and propagate to the fifo_wdata_289 array. I don't really know why this isn't a false path, since the source signal feeds into a registered ram block. Maybe it is safe to ignore (hopefully).

Comment: I'm also not sure if any of the mentioned paths don't fail. If they fail, they don't fail as hard as the paths I'm getting displayed (TimeQuest has a display/analyze limit) :D
Maybe it's also relevant to note, that the RAM is a M10K block

Comment: Thank you for your update.
I've changed the Memory cell type from M10K to MLAB and decreased the clock rate to 288 MHz, because apparently the storage cells can't handle more than that. Sadly the problems didn't disappear, the skew only decresed in amplitude, since the clock rate got decreased. I'm using asynchronous FIFOs, because I need to do CDC and for that reason I use 3 synchronisation stages, meaning, that the full/empty signals are registered inside the FIFO.

Answer (score 0):

If both FIFOs are being fed the same clock phase, then the setup and hold times for the second FIFO are being violated, as in arriving too soon. Your program is hinting that your need to slow something down, namely your clock.

You can add an inverter to latch the second FIFO on the falling edge long after the data has settled. A better option if your software can do this is to put a wiggle in the clock line before it reaches the second FIFO. Software like Specctra can do the calculations for this.

Lacking anything better a low value resistor in series with the clock to the second FIFO will create a natural delay. Find out the capacitance of the clock pin and calculate what is needed for a few nS delay. I would think 100 ohms at most, but greater than 10 ohms.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, but I wouldn't use an resistor, even if it was an analog circuit, because this will introduce noise and I don't even want to think about the EMC, when you put a 360 MHz clock on a FPGA pin and use a resistor to feed back the signal.
The FIFOs are also latched on the inverted edge, while the data is being changed on the other edge, thus Ihad hoped the data would be stable a the latching time of the FIFOs